# Is there a way to test if a variable is dynamic?

Tags: c#, dynamic

The following piece of code will always return true unless the variable `v` is `null`:

```
v is dynamic
```

and the following test will not compile ("The typeof operator cannot be used on the dynamic type"):

```
v.GetType() == typeof(dynamic)
```

So is there a way to test if the variable is `dynamic`?

Comment: For those people with a longer Microsoft experience, `dynamic` is the new `IDispatch`. Think really hard whether you want to deal with it.

Comment: Related: [how-do-i-test-for-typeofdynamic?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598731/how-do-i-test-for-typeofdynamic?rq=1)

Comment: @nawfal Interesting problem! It's a shame methods don't readily exist for that kind of problem - maybe something that will be in the next version of the DRL.

Comment: @dav_i what is the kind of dynamic you're trying to detect? Can you show us an example how variable `v` is declared and used? Or go thru the comment section of my answer, you might get better idea..

Comment: @nawfal Actually the problem I was having was the one you linked to but my question was more general. As Marc said in your comment chain - sometimes the OP (me) doesn't know what they're asking. Still - I feel changing question after so many people have answered is against the SO way.

Comment: @dav_i you need not change the question as such. You can add more details. Or ask another sub question related to the first one. Use the edit feature. It is encouraged on SO. I say this because without context, we do not know what `dynamic` is. If you already understood the concept, then that's fine. But it may help future visitors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reflect on a dynamic type to tell if it was a dynamic type, to begin with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883737/reflect-on-a-dynamic-type-to-tell-if-it-was-a-dynamic-type-to-begin-with)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Firstly, you need to separate the variable and the object. A variable is dynamic **if it is defined as `dynamic`**. That is all. There is nothing more. A *field* or *property* would be annotated with the `[Dynamic]` attribute, i.e.

```
public dynamic Foo {get;set;}
```

is actually:

```
[Dynamic]
public object Foo {get;set;}
```

This basically acts as a prompt for the compiler to access the object via the `dynamic` API rather than via the OOP API.

An *object* supports full `dynamic` capabilities if it implements `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` - however, such an object can be accessed via both the `dynamic` API and via the regular OOP API (it can have both). Equally, an object that doesn't implement `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` can be accessed via either API (but: only the public members will be available via `dynamic`).

Answer (score 14):

There is no CLR type called `dynamic`. The C# compiler makes all `dynamic` values of type `object` and then calls custom binding code to figure out how to handle them. If `dynamic` was used, it will show up as `Object`.

But You can check if an instance is of type `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` or you can check whether the type implements `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`

Comment: An instance is **never** "of type `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`", since that is not a concrete type. The type *can implement* that, of course (the second half of that sentence is fine).

Comment: @MarcGravell, from polymorphism's point of view class Foo implementing IFoo IS-A IFoo. Probably my English is not perfect.

Comment: Here is an example: `typeof(IDynamicMetaObjectProvider).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ExpandoObject))`

Answer (score 2):

In C# dynamic means no complile-time check and it's gonna have the type of the other side of the = symbol. However GetType is a runtime evaluation, so you always gonna retrieve declared type and not dynamic.

You can read a little bit more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598922.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There will always be a run-time type as others have said.

There is a hack to detect for local variables, relying on the fact that dynamic variables doesn't support extension methods.

```
static void DummyDynamicTest<T>(this T t) //extension method
{

}

dynamic test = 1;
try
{
    test.DummyDynamicTest();
    //not dynamic
}
catch (RuntimeBinderException)
{
    //dynamic
}
```

However you can't refactor the functionality into another method. This can't be very useful at all in any meaningful scenarios, ignore at any cost.

Comment: Surely checking for `test is IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` is simpler, more efficient, and more correct?

Comment: @nawful what case is that? concrete example? (genuinely interested)

Comment: @MarcGravell the same. `dynamic test = 1;`. Now `test is IDynamicMetaObjectProvider;` returns false.

Comment: ah, I see - we're talking at cross purposes: you're talking purely about the *variable*; I was talking about the *value*. When it comes to the *variable*, that is defined 100% by the variable declaration - I'm not sure how useful it actually is to "test" the defined type of a local variable, since that is *right there in the definition*. The simpler "test" there is : *look at the definition*. It is a bit like asking whether `string x;` is an `int`... well, *no* - it is a `string`. You don't need a test for that.

Comment: @MarcGravell OP is after variable declaration. I agree it is not at all useful in the context I have used. What do you mean by *value* being dynamic? I did not get that part. In other words, in which case does `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` comes handy? (genuinely interested)

Comment: it is pretty common that what the OP *asks for* is not exactly the correct words for *what they mean*. Especially with things like "variables" vs "values" vs "references", etc. Re the interface: that is the interface that the `dynamic` implementation uses to decide whether to look for reflection methods (i.e. a method called `DummyDynamicTest`, accessed normally) vs the full dynamic invoke route (a `dynamic` object can *run methods that don't exist*). In fact, it is really easy too - http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/fun-with-dynamic-how-to-build-dynamic.html

Comment: The try ... catch... expression is never a correct way of checking stuff.

Comment: @KrzysztofCieslak oh, I don't know... "can I *actually* talk to the database on this connection that claims to be open" is something where I suspect `try`/`catch` might be the only route. But I agree it seems undesirable *here*.

Comment: @MarcGravell, In such case is it really check if database is up or it is handling unexpected behaviour - database is not up ?

Comment: @KrzysztofCieslak that depends a bit on your definition of "expected" / "unexpected" ;p but yes, I think we're somewhere near the same page here

Comment: @MarcGravell ah, I understand you. So that means for something like `dynamic test = new ExpandoObject();`, `test is IDynamicMetaObjectProvider;` returns true. But I don't think OP's after such *truly* dynamic objects. Most probably he is after dynamic declarations in which case there is no reliable way.

Comment: @KrzysztofCieslak of course not, and it is written all over my answer. It wasn't a serious *solution* to OP's problem, but an *answer* that shows one aspect of `dynamic` which can be handled. Not sure who downvoted.

Answer (score -1):

@nawfal Sadly your extension method fails when any normal poco class that is not dynamic is passed in.

@Marc Gravell's proposed solution is correct. I think the confusion lies around the fact that even though you can declare anything as dynamic. However, when you instantiate it to a concrete class then it is no longer truly dynamic. Here are some tests I threw at it. Only test2 and test3 should pass. You can further test it out by trying to set some property that does **not** exist on each dynamic. Which will cause an exception on the non dynamic dynamics. :)

```
class Program
{
    private class MyDynamic: DynamicObject
    {

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic test1 = new { Name = "Tim" };
        //although I used the dynamic keyword here, it is NOT dynamic. dynamics are only dynamics if they support dynamically adding properties
        //uncommenting this line will cause an exception
        //test.LastName = "Jones"
        if (test1 is IDynamicMetaObjectProvider) { Console.WriteLine("test1"); }

        dynamic test2 = new MyDynamic();
        if (test2 is IDynamicMetaObjectProvider) { Console.WriteLine("test2"); }

        dynamic test3 = new ExpandoObject();
        if (test3 is IDynamicMetaObjectProvider) { Console.WriteLine("test3"); }

        dynamic test4 = new List<string>();
        if (test4 is IDynamicMetaObjectProvider) { Console.WriteLine("test4"); }
    }
}
```