# How to check if an Object is a AnonymousType

Tags: c#, typechecking

My First Version :

```
bool IsDynamicType(object obj){
    return obj is dynamic;
}
```

it's fault because all class object will return true,ex:

```
var b1 = new {} is dynamic; //True
var b2 = new object() is dynamic; //True
```

I know `new {}` system will compiler `<>f__AnonymousType01`.
My current way to check object is dynamic :

```
bool IsDynamicType(object obj){
    return Regex.IsMatch(obj.GetType().Name,@"AnonymousType");
}
```

I am having a problem now if class's name is `xxxAnonymousTypexxx` this function will return true.

Comment: You mean you want to check for an _anonymous_ type, right? Not `dynamic`.

Comment: `dynamic` doesn't remove strong typing from C#. Each instance still have exactly one type. Also, it's looks like you trying to determine is type of object is anonymous?

Comment: @Sweeper sorry, i have no idea the different between dynamic and anonymous

Comment: An object cannot be dynamic, only the variable to which it is assigned.

Comment: `dynamic` means: "Hey CLR, I'm sure you can handle the type of object on the go, but I guess it will have a `Name` property" `anonymous` means: "Hey CLR, I don't care how you call this type but it must contains a string `Name` property"

Comment: @Cory i got you,i fix the title `How to check if an Object is a AnonymousType`,thanks.

Comment: @ITWeiHan indeed you've likely already found your answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483023/how-to-test-if-a-type-is-anonymous) to the question you actually interested in (not the one asked originally in the post which was also [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785655/is-there-a-way-to-test-if-a-variable-is-dynamic)). If you still need more info - consider asking new question using correct terms.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov , thank you!