# How to test if a property has been declared as "dynamic"?

Tags: c#, system.reflection

As the title says, when using reflection, how can I test if a property has been declared as `dynamic`?

Unfortunately using `!pi.PropertyType.IsValueType` isn't specific enough in my case. The only way I found is to look through the `pi.CustomAttributes` array and test if it contains an item with an `AttributeType` of `DynamicAttribute`. Is there a *better* way to achieve this goal?

```
public class SomeType
{
    public dynamic SomeProp { get; set; }
}

// ...

foreach (var pi in typeof(SomeType).GetProperties())
{
    if (pi.PropertyType == typeof(string)) { } // okay
    if (pi.PropertyType == typeof(object)) { } // okay 
    if (pi.PropertyType == typeof(dynamic)) { } // The typeof operator cannot be used on the dynamic type
}
```

---

Thanks for the replies. This is how I solved it:

```
public static class ReflectionExtensions
{
    public static bool IsDynamic(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        return propertyInfo.CustomAttributes.Any(p => p.AttributeType == typeof(DynamicAttribute));
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "better". Why doesn't the [accepted way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785655/is-there-a-way-to-test-if-a-variable-is-dynamic) (the `[DynamicAttribute]` you mention) work "good enough" for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to test if a variable is dynamic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785655/is-there-a-way-to-test-if-a-variable-is-dynamic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put your code in [SharpLib.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYbACeAdgIYC2AlgMboDKA9jQKYAKATqwA750Acw4AXANzoAzuKkBfQsTSYALOgCyACgCU+JcWJtOvAegC86VBIPpFSeUA==), you can see what happens to your code behind the scenes.

```
using System;
public class C {
    public dynamic SomeProp { get; set; }
    public void M() {
        SomeProp = 3;
    }
}
```

is converted to (removed some stuff for readability):

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;

public class C
{
    [Dynamic]
    private object <SomeProp>k__BackingField;

    [Dynamic]
    public object SomeProp
    {
        [return: Dynamic]
        get
        {
            return <SomeProp>k__BackingField;
        }
        [param: Dynamic]
        set
        {
            <SomeProp>k__BackingField = value;
        }
    }

    public void M()
    {
        SomeProp = 3;
    }
}
```

The `SomeProp` property is just a plain `object` for the .Net runtime. With a `[Dynamic]` attribute attached.

There is no way to test for the dynamic type, since it is not the type of `SomeProp`. You should test for the presence of the `[Dynamic]` attribute.